# Can't find printer on ubuntu from java with print service

Tags: java, ubuntu, printing

I have problem with getting list of printers from java in ubuntu i have to find
EPSON TM88V and BIXOLON SRP350II both are connected over USB.

This is the code  i used

```
 PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
         for(int i=0;i<=service.length;i++)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,service[i]);

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and this is the solution:

```
 PrintService[] service = java.awt.print.PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

  for (int i=0;i<service.length;i++) 
  { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,service[i].getName());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's appeared to be an issue with the network printers. any printer to be seen by JRE has to be in "shared" state. unfortunately network printers aren't. the only option so far is to install cups-pdf bridge and print from Java glovebox through PDF exported file (printed by "local" PDF sink appeared in the configuration after installing cups-pdf).

the command for installing necessary cups-pdf sink:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

next, System Settings->Printers->PDF->->Shared (enable checkbox)